# How many terms in arithmetic series where sum < 1000?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm familiar with sigma notation for finding the sum of a set number of terms, but what if I want to find how many terms are in a series where the sum is $< 1000$, for example?

**Edit**: Let's say I have a series $7+19+31+43+52+...$ and I want to find out how many terms occur in that series before I hit a sum of $1000$ or greater.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't see anything in that link that explains my question.

Comment: Write down the sum for $n$ terms and then solve for $n$, remembering to find the integer part

Comment: @SimonS If I'm trying to find the sum of an unknown number of terms in a series that is less than a specific number (in this case: 1000), then how does any of that help me?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe There seems to be some confusion here.  Perhaps it would help if you gave a specific example of your problem.

Comment: If your question is only one sentence long, please make that an understandable sentence. Finding terms in a (given?) series _where_ the sum is less than $1000$ is not clear. What sum? The sum of just that term, or of the whole series, is not useful for the question. The sum of all terms up to and including that term would make sense. But then there could well be infinitely many such terms.

Comment: What *is* the series?  Is it an arithmetic progression ($a_{i+1}=k +a_i $)?  What's k and what's the first term?  Do you know how to express the term as a quadratic?  If you do, just solve the quadratic fo the sum you want.

Comment: 57.  It's exactly 57 terms.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Meanwhile you could do with some civility. How do you even sum an individual term? The term is just one number. That makes no sense to me. I will edit the question with an example. If it still doesn't make sense, feel free to request further clarification, albeit in a more genteel manner.

Comment: If your series is $5+7+9+11+...$, then the sum of $n$ terms is $n^2+4n$.  Then you solve $n^2+4n<1000$, or $(n+2)^2<1004$, which is $n\leq29$.  For your example, lab's link shows you how to find the sum for $n$ terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an arithmethic progression $$u_n=a +  (n-1)d$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^k u_n=\frac{1}{2} k (2 a+d (k-1))$$ So, if you want the largest number $k$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^k u_n<S$, you need to solve the quadratic equation $$dk^2+k (2 a-d)-2 S=0$$ for which the positive root is given by $$k_*=\frac{\sqrt{(d-2 a)^2+8 d S}-2 a+d}{2 d}$$ Let us apply to your example $(a=7,d=12,S=1000)$; the above formula gives $k_*\approx 12.8269$; so, using $13$ terms or more will give a sum larger than $1000$.

If we check, the sum of the first $12$ terms gives $876$ and the sum of the first $13$ terms gives $1027$.

Answer (score 2):

Well then you need to solve for $n$.

$$S_n<1000$$

$$0<1000-S_n$$

Solve for $n$. To do this find the values of $n$ such that $1000-S_n=0$ Using that you can find the upper and lower bounds for when $0<1000-S_n$
Depending on the complexity of $U_n$ depends on how hard this is to do with algebra. You can always put this into a graphing calculator, such as desmos.com. Hope this helps.